# I am getting the values from MySQL in command prompt. But how the values display in Chat bot?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ibm-watson

I'm creating one chat bot using IbmWatson. When user asking to my chat bot for cost of some products, then the values are coming from MySQL server. I am done all setups also get the values. But that values are display in command prompt not in Chatbot.

How to the values are display in Chat bot.

I am using Node.js

I am trying this code :

```
  function updateMessage(input, response){

    var responseText = null;
    if (response.intents && response.intents[0]) {

    var intent = response.intents[0];  
    if (intent.intent==='Sales-1'){
    var rsp = con.query("SELECT Mobiles from Salestb", function (err, 
    result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    result.forEach( (row) => {
    console.log(`${row.Mobiles}`);

    });

  });


      response.output.text = "This is the modified Output :"+ rsp;       
}  }
```

I am trying above code to getting the values in command prompt is  :

```
[ RowDataPacket { Mobiles: '2,894,564' } ]

2,894,564
```

In Chat bot :This is the modified Output :[object Object]

The values are display in Object format. But I want display Values. How to solve this ?

Comment: `con.query` is asynchronous, that's why you need to provide a callback function to process the result. `con.query()` probably returns a Promise object, and putting it into text format will thus print `[object Object]`. Plus, the query looks like you'll get multiple rows; what exactly do you want to display in your `response.output`? Anyway, whatever it is, you have to do it inside the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You get the output in the command prompt because yopu use console.log:

```
console.log(`${row.Mobiles}`);
```

you should change the response to:

```
response.output.text = "This is the modified Output :"+ ${row.Mobiles};
```

**EDIT**
Put your inside the query function like this

```
function updateMessage(input, response){

    var responseText = null;
    if (response.intents && response.intents[0]) {

        var intent = response.intents[0];  
        if (intent.intent==='Sales-1'){
            var rsp = con.query("SELECT Mobiles from Salestb", function (err,result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                result.forEach( (row) => {
                    console.log(`${row.Mobiles}`);        
                });
                response.output.text = "This is the modified Output :"+ ${row.Mobiles};
            });           
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to just return the value ($row.Mobiles ) from the function and storing in a variable on out side of the function

Comment: `row` is out of scope out of the `forEach` loop, so the data needs to be either saved or used inside the loop.